# How to integrate angular acceleration in terms of $\theta$ rather than time?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, torque, moment-of-inertia

Problem setup:

We have a rod attached to a pivot at its end. The rod has a mass $M$ and length $L$ with moment of inertia $\frac{1}{3}ML^2$. You are holding the end initially and then release it, allowing it to rotate a full 90 degrees. Here is a basic diagram: [image: this]

An interesting problem came up in physics class, that there is a way, somehow, to integrate the angular acceleration of this rod to get the final velocity.

I initially thought of the integral:

$$\int_{90^{\circ}}^{0} Mg\frac{L}{2}\sin(\theta)\ d\theta$$

Except this is going to give work, and I'm trying to avoid using energy all together and only integrate acceleration to get $\Delta\omega$ - but somehow time has to relate to the angle. I can't figure out how to proceed.

Comment: IMO not a good idea to spurn the simple solution. When you are asking how to solve using a particular mathematical technique, the question is about mathematics rather than physics. ... The result of using torque is the same as using conservation of energy. See my comment to Gert's answer.

Comment: @sammygerbil you're absolutely correct. I very well understand how to solve using energy conservation but I was curious as to how it would work with kinematics and torque.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the motion is in a two-dimensional plane, we know that $L = I\omega$, where $\omega$ is the rod's angular velocity. Further, given that $\tau = \frac{dL}{dt}$,where $\tau$ is the torque exerted by the gravitational force on the rod, we have $\tau = I \frac{d}{dt} \omega = I \alpha$. Solving for $\alpha$ we have, $\alpha =  \frac{\tau}{I}$. Because $\alpha = \frac{d\omega}{dt}$ we can integrate this expression, from the time when the rod is released ($t=0$) until the time when the rod hits the wall ($t=\sqrt{2\theta\alpha}$). It is easier to change variables and integrate with respect to the angles, but as far as I can determine, that is the logic in setting up the problem as a function of time. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

The mass $M$ exerts a torque $\tau$ about the hinge. Using Newton's second law applied to rotations:

$$\tau=\alpha I,$$

where $I$ is the inertial moment of the rod about the hinge and $\alpha=\frac{d\omega}{dt}$, with $\omega$ the angular velocity of the bar.

Note that $\tau$ depends on the angle of of the bar to the horizontal:

$$\tau=Mg\frac{L}{2} \cos\theta$$

Thus:

$$Mg\frac{L}{2}\cos\theta=I\frac{d\omega}{dt}$$

This differential equation defines $\omega=f(t)$.

Comment: To eliminate t substitute $\frac{d\omega}{dt}=\frac{d\omega}{d\theta}\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\omega \frac{d\omega}{d\theta}$.